# authentication error when publishing from gradle to nexus

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, nexus

I am using gradle v3.4 and trying to publish a jar file to nexus.  Relevant portions of build.gradle and error are copied below:

**build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username project.properties['nexusUser']
            password project.properties['nexusPassword']
        }
        url project.properties['nexusUrl']
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

I get the error below when I run **gradle clean** or **gradle dependencies**
**error**

```
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Authentication scheme 'all'(Authentication) is not supported by protocol 'file'
```

**gradle.properties**

```
nexusUrl="http://nexus.something.com"
nexusUser="someone"
nexusPassword="somepassword"
```

Comment: What are your properties set to?

Comment: updated post - i am guessing that is the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused because I was specifying the URL and other parameters in the properties.gradle with inverted commas:

```
nexusUrl="http://nexus.something.com"
nexusUser="someone"
nexusPassword="somepassword"
```

Once I removed the inverted commas, the error went away.
When I ran **gradle dependencies -s** while keeping the inverted commas, I got the following output:

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'test-something'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:599)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:125)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:233)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:160)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:455)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:446)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:446)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:422)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.doGetFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:515)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:367)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:69)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:193)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:78)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Authentication scheme 'all'(Authentication) is not supported by protocol 'file'
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.validateConnectorFactoryCredentials(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.createTransport(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.createTransport(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.getTransport(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createRealResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ResolveIvyFactory.create(ResolveIvyFactory.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.createResolvers(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:81)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:190)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:136)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:67)
```

Comment: I am not seeing inverted commas in your answer - I see double quotes.  If you removed the double quotes, wouldn't the strings be treated as variable names?  Could you post the solution that works?  TIA

Comment: @PaulMorrison use without inverted commas or quotes - i believe that was the issue and removing them fixed it. hope it helps

Answer (score 8):

I think you miss the protocol for the url, so it assumes `file://` and fails.

Comment: @alihaider ok, then please re-execute with `-s` and add the output to the question.

Comment: i moved the same url as a string in the build.gradle and the error message went away.  i will re-execute and share the output shortly

Comment: it was happening because I had the URL enclosed with inverted commas in the properties file - once I removed the inverted commas, the error went away

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `""`.

Before:

```
nexusUrl="http://nexus.something.com"
nexusUser="someone"
nexusPassword="somepassword"
```

After:

```
nexusUrl=http://nexus.something.com
nexusUser=someone
nexusPassword=somepassword
```